# Pass internal table into REUSE_ALV_FIELDCATALOG_MERGE

Tags: abap, alv

I've got `lt_result` table as result of function module, just a usual internal table with 50+ columns.

So, I have to send that to ALV display, how to properly use that table as a source for `REUSE_ALV_FIELDCATALOG_MERGE`?

```
CALL FUNCTION 'REUSE_ALV_FIELDCATALOG_MERGE'
 EXPORTING
   I_PROGRAM_NAME               = sy-repid
   I_INTERNAL_TABNAME           = 'LT_RESULT'
```

This way it compiles, but won't get any fieldnames from that table. The same, when I try to use structure.

How do i get field names from given table to `lt_fieldcat[]` with shortest way possible?

Comment: Is using the (well-documented) SALV classes an option?

Comment: Uhm. Doesn't knew about it. But it helped, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The shortest way possible is using [SALV classes](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/ABAP/ALV+Grid+Report+-+with+Object+Oriented+SALV+Classes):

```
data: gr_table  type ref to cl_salv_table.

call method cl_salv_table=>factory
  IMPORTING
    R_SALV_TABLE = gr_table
  CHANGING
    t_table      = lt_result.

gr_table->display( ).
```

This way you don't need fieldcatalog at all.

Answer (score 1):

```
    call function 'REUSE_ALV_FIELDCATALOG_MERGE'
   exporting
     i_program_name                    = sy-repid
     i_internal_tabname                = 'LT_RESULT'
     i_inclname                        = sy-repid "< if you use top-include  
    changing
     ct_fieldcat                       = lt_fldcat[]
```

When declaring lt_result using **TYPE** and not using **LIKE**